# Get raw wear leveling count of SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Due to specific needs of SSD bench-marking against heavy write, I would like to get the raw leveling count of the SSD. Is the raw value provided by CrystalDisk reliable, by which `...000C` equals `12`?

Is this globally accessible between different SSD provider, if not, how can I get the info?

[image]

Comment: That's the S.M.A.R.T value for wear leveling, so the value is accurate.

Comment: If it isn't provided by the drive then the value will not be there. Almost all SMART data is optional.

Comment: Raw values are not comparable between different manufacturers or even series. If you want to benchmark SSDs, you have but one way: Write until they die. Compare speed over time and lifetime.